# How can I add a Bar on top bottom android?

Tags: android, android-activity, styles, toolbar

I want to have a tool bar on top and another bar at bottom of my activity,
make it look like that:

[image]

Comment: What you ever tried so far? Share your code...

Comment: i tried to put a picture , and align it , but it doesn't go ful on the activity , i tried with relative layout too , but it doesn't work at least, i tried to make a that picture as a background , but it doesn't get adapted on all devices !

Comment: Images are a whole different ballgame than simple views. They have to scale differently. Post your layout code, it will be more helpful.

Comment: i don't know if i have to use layout or just images , just take a look at the picture on the top , and it may help you understanding me , i want to put 2 bars on top and on bottom , that my only problem !

Comment: You definitely need a layout...

Comment: how can i make a color to the background of the layout ? and make it fill to the top , anf right /left !?

Comment: Have you looked into any tutorials? Not even trying to be rude, but this is Android 101.

Comment: i saw many tutorials , look at the best thig i have :


`<RelativeLayout

        android:layout_width="match_parent"

        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

        android:background="#009900"

        android:gravity="top" >


        <TextView

            android:id="@+id/textView1"

            android:layout_width="wrap_content"

            android:layout_height="wrap_content"

            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"

            android:text="@string/hello_world" />



    </RelativeLayout>`


it's not like a bar !!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use Bottom navigation bars.

https://www.google.com/design/spec/components/bottom-navigation.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a linear layout and align layout on top. For bottom, create another linear layout and align layout to bottom. Add your views into the layouts.

Comment: it doesn't work like that , this is why i add a action bar and a split action bar :/

Comment: It is a very simple layout i didn't get where are you getting the problem, could you please share xml code?

Comment: `<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.UI_OPTIONS"
                android:value="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" />
            >

`

this is the way i did in , with action bar , i want to do the same thing , linear layout can't go until the marge !

Comment: Why don't you use simple style and xml? you are not clear what are you asking.

Comment: i try to have two bar , obe on the top , the second on buttom , layout don't help ,